# Changing from 2 operating systems to just Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows. Now I want to remove Windows. Is there an easier way to remove Windows than uninstalling everything and installing Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

1. Boot onto Ubuntu
2. Connect internet
3. Install and run [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller): open a new Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), then type:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller`

When the window appears, select Windows

[image]

Click `OK`, this will remove Windows (= this will format your Windows partition, then update your GRUB bootloader). The old Windows partition will be available from Ubuntu for you to place data (documents, pictures..) in it.

Comment: great, then please mark my answer as correct :)